# Archiving files with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this script that runs several executable updates in a shared network folder. Several separate machines must run these updates.
I would like to archive these updates once they are run. However, as you may see the dilemma, if the first machine runs an update and archives the executable,
the rest of connected devices won't run as they will no longer appear in the cwd. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand what you meant by "archiving", but probably moving to another folder on a network shared mount. Also, the title should definitely be changed, I accidentally marked it as OK in Review Triage system.

You probably want to assign some ID to each machine, then have each of them create a new file once they finish the installation (e.g. empty `finished1.txt` for PC with ID 1, `finished2.txt` for PC 2 etc.). Then, one "master" PC should periodically scan for such files, and when finding all it expects, deleting/moving/archiving the installers. It may be good idea to add timeout functionality to the script on master PC, so when one of PCs will get stuck, you will get notified in some way.

Comment: Yeah, moving the files to a folder with older updates. Thanks for your help!